# Tool for copying with automated renaming and moving

Tags: windows, gui

**Current status**

I have a folder hierarchy, which perfectly suits my needs when working with it.
However, I must distribute the folders and files in the near future on a flash drive. In my case, the folder hierarchy best for work isn't the same as the folder hierarchy I would like have other people to be presented with.

Manual copying and modifying of the folder hierachy is obviously prone to errors. I am therefore looking for an automated solution.

**Requirements**

- Specifying a "transformation" via a GUI (think of a GUI variant of XLST for folder hierarchies)
- Such a transformation shall allow me to:

  - rename folders and files
  - move folders and files (inside the folder hierarchy)
- Copy the original folders and files after the applied transformation to a destination location